# Passing one va_list as a parameter to another

Tags: c++, fastcgi, variadic-functions

I'm creating an application using the fastcgi library, and their method of printing is a little verbose. I'm trying to wrap their fprintf function in my own method:

I would like to turn

> FCGX_FPrintF(out, char* fmt, ...);

into

> write(char* strFormat, ...);

I've found the magic of va_list but can't find an easy way to pass va_list values into their fprintf function. Is there a way to do this? I know vsprintf and vprintf exist so it must be harder than I imagine it is.

If all else fails, I'll just overload a write function

Comment: Here's the header for the library if it helps
http://www.fastcgi.com/devkit/include/fcgiapp.h

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You would have to find the analogue of `vfprintf()` in the Fast CGI library.  It is at least moderately plausible that there is one; the easy way to implement `FCGX_FPrintF()` is:

```
void FCGX_FPrintF(FILE *out, char *fmt, ...)
{
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, fmt);
    FCGX_VFPrintF(out, fmt, args);
    va_end(args);
}
```

So it is highly probable that the function exists; you will need to check whether it is exposed officially or not.

---

A quick visit to the [Fast CGI web site](http://www.fastcgi.com/) reveals that the FCGX prefix is used by functions declared in the fgciapp.h header, and that in turn contains:

```
/*
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 *
 * FCGX_FPrintF, FCGX_VFPrintF --
 *
 *      Performs printf-style output formatting and writes the results
 *      to the output stream.
 *
 * Results:
 *      number of bytes written for normal return,
 *      EOF (-1) if an error occurred.
 *
 *----------------------------------------------------------------------
 */
DLLAPI int FCGX_FPrintF(FCGX_Stream *stream, const char *format, ...);

DLLAPI int FCGX_VFPrintF(FCGX_Stream *stream, const char *format, va_list arg);
```

So, there's the function with the interface completed.

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any way to do this in a platform independent way.
I would probably format the string myself using vsprintf then just send that to the printing function.